# d3: color options in a select list

Tags: d3.js

I have a select list -

```
<label id="brand" style="font-size:18px;" for="brand">Brand:</label>
<select id="brandOptions" style="font-size:18px;" multiple>
    <option value=0 selected>All</option>
    <option value=1>Kellog</option>
    <option value=2>Post</option>
    <option value=3>Quaker</option>
    <option value=4>General Mills</option>
    <option value=5>Tree House</option>
    <option value=6>CPW</option>
</select>
```

I have a d3 color scale -

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

I want to color each text in the multi-select with a color based on its option value.

How do I do this? I got lost trying the below which obviously doesn't work -

```
d3.selectAll("#brandOptions option")
.style("color", color(this.property("value")));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two related issues here, both are solved by passing a function to `.style()`.

Currently you pass the result of a function to `.style()`, not a function to be applied to each element in the selection - equivalent to `.style("color",functionName)` vs `.style("color",functionName(x))`.

As we aren't passing a function to `.style()` two issues arise:

1. `this` does not refer to the element being modified - it refers to the window (`this` isn't a d3 selection either, so `this.property("value")` should generate an error.
2. you aren't applying styling based on each element, but rather based on the one time you run your color function when supplying `.style()` with the result of `color(this.property("value"))`.

Both are fixed by nesting your color logic in a function that is passed to `.style()` - `this` will refer to the element being manipulated, and the function will be applied to each element individually, for example:

```
.style("color", function() { return color(d3.select(this).property("value")); })
```

Here I've placed your color logic in a function that is passed to `.style()`. This function is executed for each item in the selection.

Also, importantly, as `this` refers to the element being modified - in the function passed to .style() - we need to use `d3.select(this)` if we want to access the value property with: `.property("value")` - `this` is the element, not the selection.

We can simplify this though (and skip a d3 selection altogether), as we can access the value property directly with `this.value`

```
.style("color", function() { return color(this.value); })
```

With those changes, you should be able to get this working:

```js
var options = d3.select("#brandOptions")
   .selectAll("option");
   
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

options.style("color",function() {
   return colors(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<select id="brandOptions" style="font-size:18px;" multiple>
    <option value=0 selected>All</option>
    <option value=1>Kellog</option>
    <option value=2>Post</option>
    <option value=3>Quaker</option>
    <option value=4>General Mills</option>
    <option value=5>Tree House</option>
    <option value=6>CPW</option>
</select>
```

Just for comparison, we could execute the inline function we pass to `.style()` - passing the function's result not the function, and we can see that it is run once, and as a consequence all colors are the same:

```js
var options = d3.select("#brandOptions")
   .selectAll("option");
   
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

options.style("color",function() {
   console.log("executed")
   return colors(this.value);
}() );  // () to run the function.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<select id="brandOptions" style="font-size:18px;" multiple>
    <option value=0 selected>All</option>
    <option value=1>Kellog</option>
    <option value=2>Post</option>
    <option value=3>Quaker</option>
    <option value=4>General Mills</option>
    <option value=5>Tree House</option>
    <option value=6>CPW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: An alternative syntax would be to access the option value directly, using `options.style("color", function() { return colors(this.value); })`

Comment: @SteveR Thanks, that's an absent minded miss on my part - wasn't fully paying attention.

Comment: Wonderful!! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!